# php comentado dentro do console

Tags: php, html, console

Tenho o seguinte codigo para teste:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php
echo 'teste';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

deveria mostrar apenas escrito teste em tela, entretanto ao executar a pagina fica em branco. Ao abrir o console notei que o php estava comentado como mostro a seguir:

```
<!--?php
echo 'teste';
?-->
```

Utilizo o WampServer como servidor local.

O motivo desta duvida é este codigo:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.min.css">

    <meta name="description" content="Violate Responsive Admin Template">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Super Admin, Admin, Template, Bootstrap">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log("Entrou aqui");
          $("#checkMaster").click(function(){
            console.log("Botão Clicado");
          $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
         });
        console.log("Saiu Aqui");
    });
</script>

  </head>  
    <title>BettaDial Admin</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/form.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/calendar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/generics.css" rel="stylesheet"> 


<body id="skin-blur-chrome">

    <header id="header" class="media">
        <a href="" id="menu-toggle"></a> 
        <a class="logo pull-left" href="index.php"><img src="img/betta.png" width="160px" height="30px"></a>

        <div class="media-body">
            <div class="media" id="top-menu">


               <!-- <div id="time" class="pull-right" align="">
                    <span id="hours"></span>
                    :
                    <span id="min"></span>
                    :
                    <span id="sec"></span>
                </div>
                -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <section id="main" class="p-relative" role="main">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <aside id="sidebar">

            <!-- Sidbar Widgets -->
            <div class="side-widgets overflow">



                 <!-- Projects -->

                 <?Php
                    $query = "select classificacao, count(*) qtd from ivr_discagem  where data between CURRENT_DATE and CURRENT_DATE+1 group by classificacao";
                    $result = Populator::ConsultaDB( $query );
                    $totalclass=0;
                    $Caixa_Postal=0;
                    $Sinal_Interceptacao=0;
                    $Anuncio_Interceptacao=0;
                    $Anuncio_Desvio=0;
                    $Anuncio_Desconhecido=0;
                    $Portabilidade=0;
                    $Atendimento_Humano=0;
                    $Fax=0;
                    $Silencio=0;
                    $Falha_Discagem=0;

                    while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        $totalclass=$totalclass+$myrow['qtd'];
                        if($myrow['classificacao']==0) {$Caixa_Postal=$myrow['qtd'];}
                        if($myrow['classificacao']==2) {$Sinal_Interceptacao=$myrow['qtd'];}
                        if($myrow['classificacao']==3) {$Anuncio_Interceptacao=$myrow['qtd'];}
                        if($myrow['classificacao']==4) {$Anuncio_Desvio=$myrow['qtd'];}
                        if($myrow['classificacao']==5) {$Anuncio_Desconhecido=$myrow['qtd'];}
                        if($myrow['classificacao']==6) {$Portabilidade=$myrow['qtd'];}
                        if($myrow['classificacao']==8) {$Atendimento_Humano=$myrow['qtd'];}
                        if($myrow['classificacao']==10) {$Fax=$myrow['qtd'];}
                        if($myrow['classificacao']==11) {$Silencio=$myrow['qtd'];}
                        if($myrow['classificacao']==12) {$Falha_Discagem=$myrow['qtd'];}
                    }
                ?>
                <div class="s-widget m-b-25">
                    <h2 class="tile-title">
                        Classificação
                    </h2>

                    <div class="s-widget-body">
                        <div class="side-border">
                            <small>Atendimento Humano</small>
                            <div class="progress progress-small">
                                 <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="progress-bar tooltips progress-bar-success" style="width: <?php if($totalclass>0){echo $Atendimento_Humano/$totalclass*100;} ?>%;" data-original-title="<?php echo $Atendimento_Humano?>">
                                      <span class="sr-only"><?php echo $Atendimento_Humano; ?></span>
                                 </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="side-border">
                            <small>Caixa Postal</small>
                            <div class="progress progress-small">
                                 <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="progress-bar tooltips progress-bar-info" style="width: <?php if($totalclass>0){echo $Caixa_Postal/$totalclass*100;} ?>%;" data-original-title="<?php echo $Caixa_Postal;?>">
                                      <span class="sr-only"><?php echo $Caixa_Postal; ?></span>
                                 </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="side-border">
                            <small>Sinal Interceptação</small>
                            <div class="progress progress-small">
                                 <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="progress-bar tooltips progress-bar-warning" style="width: <?php if($totalclass>0){echo $Sinal_Interceptacao/$totalclass*100;} ?>%;" data-original-title="<?php echo $Sinal_Interceptacao; ?>">
                                      <span class="sr-only"><?php echo $Sinal_Interceptacao; ?></span>
                                 </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="side-border">
                            <small>Anúncio Interceptação</small>
                            <div class="progress progress-small">
                                 <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="progress-bar tooltips progress-bar-warning" style="width: <?php if($totalclass>0){echo $Anuncio_Interceptacao/$totalclass*100;} ?>%;" data-original-title="<?php echo $Anuncio_Interceptacao; ?>">
                                      <span class="sr-only"><?php echo $Anuncio_Interceptacao; ?></span>
                                 </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="side-border">
                            <small>Anúncio Desvio</small>
                            <div class="progress progress-small">
                                 <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="progress-bar tooltips progress-bar-warning" style="width: <?php if($totalclass>0){echo $Anuncio_Desvio/$totalclass*100;} ?>%;" data-original-title="<?php echo $Anuncio_Desvio; ?>%">
                                      <span class="sr-only"><?php echo $Anuncio_Desvio; ?></span>
                                 </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="side-border">
                            <small>Anúncio Desconhecido</small>
                            <div class="progress progress-small">
                                 <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="progress-bar tooltips progress-bar-warning" style="width: <?php if($totalclass>0){echo $Anuncio_Desconhecido/$totalclass*100;} ?>%;" data-original-title="<?php echo $Anuncio_Desconhecido; ?>">
                                      <span class="sr-only"><?php echo $Anuncio_Desconhecido; ?></span>
                                 </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="side-border">
                            <small>Portabilidade</small>
                            <div class="progress progress-small">
                                 <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="progress-bar tooltips progress-bar-warning" style="width: <?php if($totalclass>0){echo $Portabilidade/$totalclass*100;} ?>%;" data-original-title="<?php echo $Portabilidade; ?>">
                                      <span class="sr-only"><?php echo $Portabilidade; ?></span>
                                 </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>                          
                        <div class="side-border">
                            <small>Fax</small>
                            <div class="progress progress-small">
                                 <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="progress-bar tooltips progress-bar-warning" style="width: <?php if($totalclass>0){echo $Fax/$totalclass*100;} ?>%;" data-original-title="<?php echo $Fax; ?>">
                                      <span class="sr-only"><?php echo $Fax; ?></span>
                                 </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="side-border">
                            <small>Silencio</small>
                            <div class="progress progress-small">
                                 <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="progress-bar tooltips progress-bar-warning" style="width: <?php if($totalclass>0){echo $Silencio/$totalclass*100;} ?>%;" data-original-title="<?php echo $Silencio; ?>">
                                      <span class="sr-only"><?php echo $Silencio; ?></span>
                                 </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="side-border">
                            <small>Falha Discagem</small>
                            <div class="progress progress-small">
                                 <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="progress-bar tooltips progress-bar-danger" style="width: <?php if($totalclass>0){echo $Falha_Discagem/$totalclass*100;} ?>%;" data-original-title="<?php echo $Falha_Discagem; ?>">
                                      <span class="sr-only"><?php echo $Falha_Discagem; ?></span>
                                 </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Side Menu -->
            <ul class="list-unstyled side-menu">
                <li class="active">
                    <a class="sa-side-home" href="index.php">
                        <span class="menu-item">Dashboard</span>
                    </a>
                </li>



        <?php

            $verifica = sprintf("select * from bettaivr.public.ivr_users where perfil = 'c' and username = '%s' ",$logado);
            $resultado = Populator::ConsultaDB( $verifica );
             if(pg_affected_rows($resultado)>0){
                // Oculta a configuração do lider de equipe
              echo ' <!-- <li>
                    <a class="sa-side-table" href="config.php">
                        <span class="menu-item">Configuração</span>
                    </a>
                </li> -->
            <li>
               </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="sa-side-table" href="logout.php">
                        <span class="menu-item">Logout</span>
                    </a> 
                    </li>' ;  
             }else{
                // Acesso a configuração do Supervisor
            $verificaSuper = sprintf("select * from bettaivr.public.ivr_users where perfil = 'b' and username = '%s' "
                ,$logado);
            $resultadoSuper = Populator::ConsultaDB( $verificaSuper );
             if(pg_affected_rows($resultadoSuper)>0){
                echo '<li>
                    <a class="sa-side-config" href="configSupervisor.php">
                        <span class="menu-item">Configuração</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                   <li>
                    <a class="sa-side-warning" href="warningview.php">
                        <span class="menu-item">Tela de Warning</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="sa-side-table" href="logout.php">
                        <span class="menu-item">Logout</span>
                    </a> 
                    </li>
                ' ;
             }else{
                // Acesso a configuração do Administrador
                 echo '<li>
                    <a class="sa-side-config" href="config.php">
                        <span class="menu-item">Configuração</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="sa-side-warning" href="warningview.php">
                        <span class="menu-item">Tela de Warning</span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="sa-side-ui" href="">
                        <span class="menu-item">Configurações de Usuário</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled menu-item">
                        <li><a href="register.php">Criar Usuário</a></li>
                        <li><a href="edit.php">Editar Usuário</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="sa-side-table" href="logout.php">
                        <span class="menu-item">Logout</span>
                    </a> 
                    </li>' ;
             }
         }



        ?>


            </ul>

        </aside>

        <?Php
            /*$result = Populator::painel1();*/

            $query = "SELECT status, available, mailing, lastdial, calling, staffed, pacing FROM bettaivr.public.ivr_status where campanha = 1 limit 1";
            $result = Populator::ConsultaDB( $query );
            $canais = 0;
            $mailing = 0;
            $aglogados = 0;
            $agdisp = 0;
            while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $canais = $myrow['calling'];
                $mailing = $myrow['mailing'];
                $agdisp = $myrow['available'];
                $aglogados = $myrow['staffed'];
            }

            $arrocupados = array( 0 => 0, 1 => 0,2 => 0,3 => 0,4 => 0,5 => 0,6 => 0,7 => 0,8 => 0,9 => 0,10 => 0,11 => 0,12 => 0 );             
            $arrmailing = array( 0 => 0, 1 => 0,2 => 0,3 => 0,4 => 0,5 => 0,6 => 0,7 => 0,8 => 0,9 => 0,10 => 0,11 => 0,12 => 0 );      
            $arravailable = array( 0 => 0, 1 => 0,2 => 0,3 => 0,4 => 0,5 => 0,6 => 0,7 => 0,8 => 0,9 => 0,10 => 0,11 => 0,12 => 0 );        
            $arrstaffed = array( 0 => 0, 1 => 0,2 => 0,3 => 0,4 => 0,5 => 0,6 => 0,7 => 0,8 => 0,9 => 0,10 => 0,11 => 0,12 => 0 );
            //$query = "SELECT to_char(atualizado,'HH24:mi') hora, round(avg(available)) available, round(avg(mailing)) mailing, round(avg(calling)) calling, round(avg(staffed)) staffed FROM bettaivr.public.ivr_status_history
            //          where atualizado between '2018/01/26'  and '2018/01/27' group by to_char(atualizado,'HH24:mi') order by to_char(atualizado,'HH24:mi') desc limit 13";

            $query = "SELECT to_char(atualizado,'HH24:mi') hora, round(avg(available)) available, round(avg(mailing)) mailing, round(avg(calling)) calling, round(avg(staffed)) staffed FROM bettaivr.public.ivr_status_history
                        where atualizado between CURRENT_DATE  and CURRENT_DATE+1 group by to_char(atualizado,'HH24:mi') order by to_char(atualizado,'HH24:mi') desc limit 13";

            $resultchart = Populator::ConsultaDB( $query );
            $i = pg_num_rows($resultchart) -1;
            //$i =0;
            while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($resultchart)) {
                $arrocupados[$i]= $myrow['calling'];
                $arrmailing[$i]= $myrow['mailing'];
                $arravailable[$i]= $myrow['available'];
                $arrstaffed[$i]= $myrow['staffed'];
                $i=$i-1;
            }

            $string_ocupados = implode("|", $arrocupados);
            $string_mailing = implode("|", $arrmailing);
            $string_available = implode("|", $arravailable);
            $string_staffed= implode("|", $arrstaffed);

            $query = "select to_char(data,'HH24') hora, count(*) dial from ivr_discagem where data between CURRENT_DATE  and CURRENT_DATE+1 group by to_char(data,'HH24') order by 1";
            $resultdialchart = Populator::ConsultaDB( $query );
            echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo ' var $resultado_discagem = [';
            $y=0;
            $intlim=0;
            $totalparcial=0;
            while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($resultdialchart)) {
                if ($y!=0) { echo ',';}
                echo '[';
                echo $myrow['hora'];
                echo ',';
                echo $myrow['dial'];
                echo ']';
                $y = (int)$myrow['hora'];
                if ($myrow['dial'] > $intlim) { $intlim = $myrow['dial'];}
                $totalparcial = $totalparcial + $myrow['dial'];
            }
            //echo '[';
            //echo $y+1;
            //echo ',0]];';
            echo '];';
            echo 'var $limitegraf = ';
            echo $intlim + 10;
            echo ';';
            echo '</script>';

        ?>


        <script type="text/javascript"> var $string_ocupados = "<?php echo $string_ocupados; ?>"; var $resultado_ocupados = $string_ocupados.split("|"); </script>  
        <script type="text/javascript"> var $string_mailing = "<?php echo $string_mailing; ?>"; var $resultado_mailing = $string_mailing.split("|");</script>   
        <script type="text/javascript"> var $string_available = "<?php echo $string_available; ?>"; var $resultado_available = $string_available.split("|");</script>   
        <script type="text/javascript"> var $string_staffed = "<?php echo $string_staffed; ?>"; var $resultado_staffed = $string_staffed.split("|");</script>   



               <!-- Content -->
        <section id="content" class="container">
            <!-- Breadcrumb -->
          <section id="login">


        <div class="clearfix"></div>


        <!-- Register -->


        <form name="frm_warning" id="box-register" method="POST" action="controllerWarning.php">
            <h2 class="m-t-0 m-b-15">Warning</h2>

             <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">


                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table id="data-table" class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                 <td></td>
                                 <td></td>
                                 <td></td>
                                 <td></td>

                                <td><p><input type="checkbox" id="checkMaster" name="checkMaster"> Selecionar Todos</p></td>

                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <th>Nome</th>
                                    <th>Telefone</th>
                                    <th>Numero de tentativas</th>
                                    <th>Ultima Tentativa</th>
                                    <th>Zerar Tentativas?</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>


                                <?php 

                            /*    function inverteData($data){
                                    if(count(explode("/",$data)) > 1){
                                        return implode("-",array_reverse(explode("/",$data)));
                                    }elseif(count(explode("-",$data)) > 1){
                                    return implode("/",array_reverse(explode("-",$data)));
                                    }
                                }; */

                                    $query = sprintf("select * from ivr_contatos, ivr_campanha where ivr_contatos.campanha = ivr_campanha.id and ivr_contatos.status = 0 and tentativas >= 5" );
                                    $result = Populator::ConsultaDB($query);

                                    while ($resultado = pg_fetch_array($result) ) {
                                        $nome = $resultado['nome'];
                                        $telefone = $resultado['telefone'];
                                        $tentativa = $resultado['tentativas'];
                                        $lastAttempt = $resultado['atualizado'];
                                        $dataconvertida = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($lastAttempt));
                                        $codigo = $resultado['codigo'];

                               echo '         

                                <tr>
                                    <td>'.$nome.'</td>
                                    <td>'.$telefone.'</td>
                                    <td align="center">'.$tentativa.'</td>
                                    <td>'.$dataconvertida.'</td>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" class="marcar" id="check" value='.$codigo.' name="check[]"/></td>
                                </tr>
                                ';
                                    }
                                ?>


                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Resubmit" class="btn btn-sm m-r-5" />

        </form>

        <!-- Forgot Password -->
    <!-- Javascript Libraries -->
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>  <!-- jQuery Library -->

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!--  Form Related -->
    <script src="js/icheck.js"></script> <!-- Custom Checkbox + Radio -->

    <!-- All JS functions -->
    <script src="js/functions.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



        </section>
    </section>

    <!-- Javascript Libraries -->
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- jQuery Library -->
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> <!-- jQuery UI -->
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script> <!-- jQuery Easing - Requirred for Lightbox + Pie Charts-->
     <script src="vendors/bower_components/jqTree/tree.jquery.js"></script>



    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Charts -->
    <script src="js/charts/jquery.flot.js"></script> <!-- Flot Main -->
    <script src="js/charts/jquery.flot.time.js"></script> <!-- Flot sub -->
    <script src="js/charts/jquery.flot.animator.min.js"></script> <!-- Flot sub -->
    <script src="js/charts/jquery.flot.resize.min.js"></script> <!-- Flot sub - for repaint when resizing the screen -->


      <!-- Vendors: Data tables -->
    <script src="vendors/bower_components/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/bower_components/datatables.net-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/bower_components/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/bower_components/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/bower_components/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>

    <!-- App functions and actions -->
    <script src="js/app.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/sparkline.min.js"></script> <!-- Sparkline - Tiny charts -->
    <script src="js/easypiechart.js"></script> <!-- EasyPieChart - Animated Pie Charts -->
    <script src="js/charts.js"></script> <!-- All the above chart related functions -->

    <!-- Map -->
    <script src="js/maps/jvectormap.min.js"></script> <!-- jVectorMap main library -->
    <script src="js/maps/usa.js"></script> <!-- USA Map for jVectorMap -->

    <!--  Form Related -->
    <script src="js/icheck.js"></script> <!-- Custom Checkbox + Radio -->

    <!-- UX -->
    <script src="js/scroll.min.js"></script> <!-- Custom Scrollbar -->

    <!-- Other -->
    <script src="js/calendar.min.js"></script> <!-- Calendar -->
    <script src="js/feeds.min.js"></script> <!-- News Feeds -->


    <!-- All JS functions -->
    <script src="js/functions.js"></script>
</body>
```

Nele utilizo PHP + HTML + CSS + Jquery com extensão .php

entretanto quando uso o botão de selecionar todos ele não entra no jquery como deveria ocorrer. em pesquisas falam que por se tratar do lado do client não tera comunicação com o lado do servidor mesmo estando fora da tag .

Comment: O servidor está ligado e funcionando? Já tentou reiniciar ele?

Comment: da um control+ F5 para atualizar a pagina e eliminar os cookies tb verifique se a pagina esta .php

Comment: Sim, esta funcional o servidor. 
Estou utilizando como .html a extensão devido a necessidade de realizar um teste do lado client invés do lado server.

Comment: e o wamp está configurado pra processar .html como PHP?

Comment: Se você deixar a extenção .html o servidor local não vai executar nada de php daquele arquivo

Comment: Não sei dizer Bacco, onde verifico essa configuração?

Comment: Guilherme, não existe forma de fazer o servidor reconhecer como php como disse o bacco?

Comment: Acredito que sim, mas pra que todo esse trabalho? Se você possui código php use a extenção .php

Comment: Devido ao seguinte, eu tenho uma pagina .php onde executo comandos php, entretanto quando tento chamar um jquery dentro dela, a mesma passa em branco pelo jquery, em algumas pesquisas falam que como jquery esta do lado do client e não do servidor ele não sera executado mesmo. minha ideia é realizar o teste pelo lado client (.html )

Comment: o PHP nunca irá funcionar em uma extensão .html. Você precisa colocar o jquery dentro de uma tag <script> e fora de qualquer tag do php <?

Comment: certo, vou comentar o problema inicial que gerou essa duvida

Comment: Voce usou `<?Php` coloque o p em minúsculo: `<?php`

Comment: ja fiz essa alteração e continua na mesma.

Comment: O que não está acontecendo e que deveria?

Comment: ao clicar no checkBox selecionar todos, deveria selecionar todos os demais checkbox. Faço isso por meio de um jquery, entretanto ele não reconhece o comando click da jquery